# javascript post request not seen by server

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to do a simple post from javascript to php, and am not getting data to transfer.  I'm using Apache2 on Ubuntu.  If I run the php code in Mozilla, it does what I've asked, but when called from javascript php does not seem to get the info to php on the server side.  I've tried to simplify the code to focus on just the post function.  Here is the html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Post Test </title>
</head>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "post_test.php";
    var file_data = "text string";
    http.open("POST", url, true);
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200){
          document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=this.responseText
        };
    }
http.send(file_data);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the php:

```
<?php
var_dump(isset($_POST['file_data']));
?>
```

I get a bool(false) message on the screen.
I checked the file access.  Both files are set rwx for all.
I am trying to learn html,javascript, and php.  I'd like to hold off on jQuery until I can do more.

Comment: Have you looked at the browser's developer tools, specifically the network and console tabs to see what's going on?

Comment: I do have the developer console enabled.  No errors show.  I also don't see errors in the apache error log.

Answer (score 1):

You should indicate in the data which field name it should go under. In your case it is file_data.

```
var myData = "file_data=foo";
http.send(myData);
```

Then your php

```
<?php
   var_dump(isset($_POST['file_data']));
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are sending PHP a string of plain text. You've made no mention of "file_data" in the string you are sending to the server, so where do you expect PHP to pick up on that name for the key in `$_POST`? PHP runs on the server, it can't see your JS variable names.

PHP will populate `$_POST` with data formatted according to the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `multipart/form-data` data formats.

You can build `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` like so:

```
http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
var data = "file_data=" + encodeURIComponent(file_data);
http.send(data);
```

Comment: Thanks Quentin.  I didn't understand the importance of the headers.  It is working now.